# How to list all available views in clickhouse DB?

Tags: clickhouse

I am new in clickhouse so it might be obvious but I haven't found a solution after an hour of searching.
I tried to do `show views` to get list of all available views in my DB, but got an error:

```
Syntax error: failed at position 6 ('views'):

show views;

Expected one of: TABLES, CLUSTER, CHANGED, GRANTS, CREATE, ACCESS, QUOTA, SETTINGS, CURRENT ROLES, PRIVILEGES, PROCESSLIST, CLUSTERS, DATABASES, CURRENT QUOTA, ENABLED ROLES, CREATE, DICTIONARIES, USERS, ROLES, SETTINGS PROFILES, PROFILES, ROW POLICIES, POLICIES, QUOTAS
```

I checked the official doc on how to list your views but found nothing.

Please, point me out how to get the list of `views` in clickhouse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select database, name from system.tables where engine = 'View'

Comment: thank you! it is working but I slightly modified where clause to filter by `MaterializedView` as I use them